# How can I get the Firebase token?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I get token value? I'm using firebase, swift3, xcode8

Token value is nil.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class TestViewController: UIViewController {
// FCM Messaging test
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()

       print("Token is \(token)")
}
```

console log `"Token is nil"`

Comment: Where did you configure firebase? in AppDelegate?

Comment: @DarshanKarekar Yes in AppDelegate. like this https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: try storing token in appDelegate itself. may be using NSUserDefaults and print it in your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same issue, i solved it by adding the below code

```
     func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

and then

```
func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
     //    NOTE: It can be nil here
           if let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
              refreshedToken = token
                print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

        }
    }
```

Check the console, if you are getting the token.

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. Are you putting this in app delegate? Where is the return variable for the first function? And wheyou declare refreshedToken?

Comment: Yeah put this in app delegate. The refreshed token will be sometimes null. So if the token is refreshed this method observes and calls. refreshed token is a global variable, it will be used as your token for Push notification